# How do you escape out of an alert box and resume flow of action? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

So i am writing a simple javascript timer, and at 30 seconds it prompts the user with an alert box if they would like to reset the count down or let it continue.
I am able to reset the timer however I get stuck when the user clicks cancel on the alert box.

I tried letting the timer just resume at its current time but that doesn't help as the alert box just keeps reappearing

I am still very new to javascript so I would like to stay using vanilla js till I get a deeper understanding of the fundamentals!

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Heres my code:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        
        if(timer<30){
            var message = confirm("Would you like to extend timer?");
            
            if (message == true) {
                timer = 60 * 1;
            } 
            
            else{
                timer = timer;
                
            }
            
        }
        

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}


function resetTimer() {
  timer = 60 * 1;
}





window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 1,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Comment: Just don't do anything in your "else" ?

Comment: @NikitaChayka when I do that, it just continues to prompt each second

Comment: that sets the timer back to 60 seconds but that does break out of the alert box, i tried doing timer = timer; but that didnt work : /

Comment: Yeah yeah i got it now, was typing an actual answer, but @Codeek did first, his answer is correct

Comment: The interval that is running this function every second isn't going to stop if there's a confirm dialog on the screen.  Also you will not get accurate timing using this technique, if that's a requirement use a date variable.

Comment: You need to store the timer id and call [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) if the user hits cancel in the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

just put `if(timer==30)` instead of `if(timer<30)` so that exactly at count of 30 units of time, you get asked once for confirmation at that instance (However be aware that until the confirmation is done, prompts will keep popping up every second). if you extend it, it will again wait till your timer goes down to 30 unit, else it will simply go down to 0 and break out.

Comment: This will keep queuing up sub 30 calls while the confirm dialog is open. If the confirm dialog is open for 5 seconds, the `setInterval`'d function will be ran 5 times the moment it is closed.

Comment: @JohnSmith agreed. I just gave him a conditional correction he was missing. Plus that will be another problem that the op will have to come up with a solution of. one possible solution would be simply decrementing the timer by one immediately before prompting the user for continuation if the op wants to continue countdown even after the alert box is open (ideal case). if not, then might have to tweak it a bit. but hey.. let him do some work on it. If he doesn't face the problem himself.. he will not have the foresight in future while architecting bigger solutions

Answer (score 1):

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes,
    seconds;

  function timerFunc() {
    timer -= 1;
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (timer == 30) {
      var message = confirm("Would you like to extend timer?");

      if (message == true) {
        timer = 60;
      } else return alert("Your timer has been stopped.")
    }
     setTimeout(timerFunc, 1000);
  }

  timerFunc();
}
```